# Which is the best way to structure the index.php file in Silex?

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I am developing a website with Silex, and due to this new approach to me (everything on a single file), I have some doubts.

**How do you structure your controllers and so?**

What I have done is to have index.php with 3 single require files:

- **config.php**:
  includes autoload and any required file, holds all the configurations and prepares any information that should be accessible at any time.
- **front_controllers.php**: does all the front stuff.
- **back_controllers.php**: includes any controller related to my backend.

Do you find this is a good choice? Otherwise, is there anything I am missing (maybe a working pattern to organize all of this)?

Comment: Please, read the official documentation before asking common questions http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#modularity

Comment: My mistake, silex has lots of advantages, but trying to find information around the docs is sort of difficult to me with that kind of organisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In additional to my comment i suggest the next file sturcture

```
web
    frontend
        default.php
        blog.php
        forum.php
        ...
    backend
        default.php
        blog.php
        forum.php
        ...
```

If the forum controller becomes too big you can divide its functionality into several files and place them in the appropriate folder. For example:

```
web
    frontend
        forum
            default.php
            subjects.php
            posts.php
            ...
```

Comment: Looks good to me, more or less what I was thinking about. Something similar could occur with Twig templates then, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, like in symfony 2 framework (i have not tried Silex yet). But i think its better to use the framework for "big" sites, not sure though.